# Why I cant access table from sub query in main query. I'm unable to do order by

Tags: oracle

`select * from (select s.name, s.age, s.number, st.time  from Student s, School st) order by s.location;`

I have already tried with the following query
select * from (select name, age, number from Student s order by s.name);

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your actual query, it makes sense to have a subquery.  Either assign the subquery an alias of `s` (though it's generally not a great idea to use the same alias for multiple things) or just `order by name` rather than `order by s.name` or assign the subquery a different alias and order by that.

Any of these should be syntactically valid

```
select name, age, number 
  from Student s
 order by s.name

select *
  from (select name, age, number 
          from Student s) s
 order by s.name

select *
  from (select name, age, number 
          from Student s)
 order by name

select *
  from (select name, age, number 
          from Student s) s2
 order by s2.name
```

Comment: if there are multiple tables in sub query how can we  make an alias

Comment: @Shankar - You can alias the entire subquery (as I show in versions 2 and 4) and sort by one of the columns returned by the subquery.  But you can't reference an alias from the subquery in the outer query.  It looks like in your edit (which is now doing a Cartesian product using the old implicit join syntax), you're trying to order by a column that isn't returned by the subquery which isn't going to work.  If you want to order by `location`, the subquery would need to return `location`.  In the subquery, of course, you'd reference `s.location`.